# Moved from Japan to the US, how do I update apt-get to use local repositories?

Tags: apt

I moved from Japan to the US recently, and using apt-get has been really slow since. It should have been obvious, but I noticed that it's getting everything from Japanese servers, which must be the reason. How can I update this?

Answer (score 2):

You can update it in 'Software and Update' (or 'Software Sources' in other releases).

## Procedure

### Open System Settings

Click on the cog in the top right corner -> click on 'System Settings'
[image: Opening system settings]

### Open Software and Updates / Software Sources

Next click on 'Software and Updates' (or 'Software Sources')
[image: Opening 'Software and Updates' from 'System Settings']

### Change server

Lastly change the server at the 'Download from' option and enter your password when asked to save the new setting.
[image: Changing apt-get server]

Comment: I don't see "software and updates" in my system settings... I'm on 12.04, if that makes a difference

Comment: @limp_chimp that does make a difference :). I think it is called 'Software Sources' under 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and copy and paste this command:

```
gksu software-properties-gtk
```

hit enter a small window will open, enter your user password, then software sources opens and you will see where to change the server setting.

Newer ubuntu releases may not have gksu installed so you may have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

[image]